# How to use OAuth with AngularJS font and Python Flask back

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs, oauth

We have a web project that use AngularJS for the front framework and Python Flask for the backend microframework.

What library/tool can I use to handle OAuth authentification

I found this but I think it doesn't handle the Python backend framework :

https://oauth.io

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Given that you're considering external providers to handle all those small details of user authentication and token issuance I would suggest you to give a look at Auth0 <sup>([recently included](https://www.thoughtworks.com/pt/radar/platforms/auth0) in Thoughtworks technology radar)</sup>.

We have a fairly big library of SDK's, samples and documentation covering a wide range of technologies; including Python.

More specifically, **for a Python Flask based API you can start by taking a look at the [Python API](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/backend/python) quickstart** which does make use of Flask.

There's also material about integrating SPA's that rely on Angular:

- [Angular 1.x Introduction](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/angularjs)
- [Angular 2 Introduction](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/angular2)

---

**Disclosure:** As you might have imagined, I'm an Auth0 engineer.